# User Logon/Logoff Information using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to check a remote computer's user logon/logoff sessions and times and I have the following code that I got from stackoverflow, but I cannot figure out how to tell the script to check a remote computer:

```
$UserProperty = @{n="User";e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier  
$_.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
$TypeProperty = @{n="Action";e={if($_.EventID -eq 7001) {"Logon"} else {"Logoff"}}}
$TimeProeprty = @{n="Time";e={$_.TimeGenerated}}

Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProeprty
```

I did do throw in a $Computername variable and a Foreach loop statment like in the following to try and get it to run on a remote computer, but it keeps checking the local system that I am on, not the remote system:

```
$Computername = Read-Host "Enter Computername Here"

Foreach $Computer in $Computername

    {
        $UserProperty = @{n="User";e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
        $TypeProperty = @{n="Action";e={if($_.EventID -eq 7001) {"Logon"} else {"Logoff"}}}
        $TimeProeprty = @{n="Time";e={$_.TimeGenerated}}

        Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProeprty
    }
```

Comment: Just adding a comment that the foreach statement is missing the parenthesis characters.  Should show as "Foreach ($Computer in $Computername)" instead.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but no answer was ever accepted.  One of the problems is that the script doesn't show which machine the user was logged into.  Anyway, I fixed it up (including the typo).

`Get-LogonHistory.ps1`:

```
param(
    [alias("CN")]
    $ComputerName="localhost"
)

$UserProperty = @{n="User";e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
$TypeProperty = @{n="Action";e={if($_.EventID -eq 7001) {"Logon"} else {"Logoff"}}}
$TimeProperty = @{n="Time";e={$_.TimeGenerated}}
$MachineNameProperty = @{n="MachinenName";e={$_.MachineName}}

foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
    Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName $computer | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProperty,$MachineNameProperty
}
```

With this, it will show which machine the user logged into.  Multiple remote computers can be passed into the command line with commas between each (no spaces).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Get-EventLog` cmdlet's `ComputerName` parameter:

```
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $Computer System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon `
    | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProeprty
```

Also, it looks like you have a typo in your `$TimeProeprty` variable.

Comment: I tried that as well and it spit out a nice long error. However, I did try removing some code and see where it hangs and this runs fine: Get-EventLog -ComputerName $Computer System, but where it seems to cause issue is the -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon portion of the script.

Comment: It might be a matter of that source not being referenced by any log entries.  You can try running `Get-EventLog -ComputerName $Computer -LogName 'System' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Source' -Unique | Sort-Object` to see what log sources are actually available on that system.  Testing with Windows XP and 7 machines, I can see that `Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon` is returned as a source on 7 but not XP.

Comment: I am testing on both Win 7 and XP. I will try what you suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A bit modified and its working

```
# Specify the location you want the report to be saved
$filelocation = "C:\report.csv"

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') 
[string]$Computer = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter     ComputerName", "Computer Name", "Computer Name")
[int]$DayPrompt = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Number of Days to     check", "Days to Check", "15")
$Days = $DayPrompt
cls

$Result = @()
Write-Host "Gathering Event Logs, this can take awhile..."
$ELogs = Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-WinLogon -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-    $Days) -ComputerName $Computer
If ($ELogs)
{ Write-Host "Processing..."
ForEach ($Log in $ELogs)
{ If ($Log.InstanceId -eq 7001)
{ $ET = "Logon"
}
ElseIf ($Log.InstanceId -eq 7002)
{ $ET = "Logoff"
}
Else
{ Continue
}
$Result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Time = $Log.TimeWritten
'Event Type' = $ET
User = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $Log.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
}
}
$Result | Select Time,"Event Type",User | Sort Time -Descending | Export-CSV $filelocation
Write-Host "Done look at $filelocation"
}
Else
{ Write-Host "Problem with $Computer."
Write-Host "If you see a 'Network Path not found' error, try starting the Remote Registry service on that computer."
Write-Host "Or there are no logon/logoff events (XP requires auditing be turned on)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the computer name to any command in the loop.  So it's just looping through the same command for as many objects are in $computerName Try changing the last line to this:

```
 Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName $computer | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProperty
```

If that doesn't work, make sure that your foreach loop is passing the right data:

```
$computerName | Foreach-Object{Write-Host $_}
```

That should display the computer name of each of the machine's you're trying to run this on.

But it looks like you're trying to run it for one computer, so remove the Foreach loop and just add `-ComputerName $computername` to the end of the Get-Eventlog command before your select statement

Comment: Dude, you replied fast. I will give your recommendations a shot real quick and let you know the outcome. But I gotta go grab some coffee first. I will be right back. Thanks Chris.

Comment: Okay, I did do what you suggested but still the same results. I just read that the Get-Eventlog cmdlet actually does provide remote access here: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-powershell/powershell-makes-security-log-access-easy.

Comment: Make this a bit simpler first.  Replace your entire script AFTER the prompt from computer name with this: Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName $ComputerName

Comment: yeah, I did this too and I keep getting back the "Get-EventLog : No matches found" error, yet if I remove the -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon it runs just fine on the remote computer. For some reason, it does not like the -Source parameter when running on remote systems.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Log-Parser-to-Identify-8aac36bd

```
Get-Eventlog -LogName Security | where {$_.EventId -eq "4624"} | select-object @{Name="User"
;Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[5]}} | sort-object User -unique
```

You can grab other info from ReplacementStrings. You can also specify a remote computer in the Get-Eventlog command.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Specify the location you want the report to be saved
$filelocation = "C:\Path\report.csv"

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') 
[string]$Computer = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter     ComputerName", "Computer Name", "Computer Name")
[int]$DayPrompt = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Number of Days to     check", "Days to Check", "15")
$Days = $DayPrompt
cls

$Result = @()
Write-Host "Gathering Event Logs, this can take awhile..."
$ELogs = Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-WinLogon -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-    $Days) -ComputerName $Computer
If ($ELogs)
{ Write-Host "Processing..."
ForEach ($Log in $ELogs)
{ If ($Log.InstanceId -eq 7001)
{ $ET = "Logon"
}
ElseIf ($Log.InstanceId -eq 7002)
{ $ET = "Logoff"
}
Else
{ Continue
}
$Result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Time = $Log.TimeWritten
'Event Type' = $ET
User = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $Log.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
}
}
$Result | Select Time,"Event Type",User | Sort Time -Descending | Export-CSV $filelocation -  TypeInformation
Write-Host "Done."
}
Else
{ Write-Host "Problem with $Computer."
Write-Host "If you see a 'Network Path not found' error, try starting the Remote Registry service on that computer."
Write-Host "Or there are no logon/logoff events (XP requires auditing be turned on)"
}
```