# Powershell - Getting Last Log Off Date and Time of a computer

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm not very good with powershell so here goes.

I'm having trouble with displaying the last logoff Date and time of a computer. So far I have:

```
$Logoff = GWMI -Comp $strComputer -Cl Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | 
    foreach-object {Write-Host "Last Logoff: "$_.Lastlogoff}
```

This gives me a list of I guess logoff dates and time. This seemed ok so I tried to convert the output using ConvertToDateTime to get a readable date/time but I don't now how to get it to work when a selection of datetimes are sent back. I've tried:

```
$Logoff = GWMI -Comp $strComputer -Cl Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | 
    foreach-object {Write-Host "Last Logoff: "ConvertToDateTime($_)}
```

but as you can guess this didn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction? Maybe I'm going about this wrong and I should be looking at a different way of getting  last logoff/logoff details

Answer (score 2):

Another way of achieving the same result as Ansgar's suggested command:

```
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $Computer -LogName 'Security' -InstanceId 4634 -newest 1 | Select-object TimeGenerated
```

On my computer, there was a big difference in time taken to retrieve the result.

Comment: Filtering in `get-wmiobject` should be much faster than piping to `where-object` in almost every case. The former does the filtering at the source; the latter retrieves *everything*, then sifts through it all to find the data you want. Filter as far to the left as you can, always.

Comment: Hi, The problem, with this is that there are loads of 4634 events for today, even though the computer has only been logged in/out once, the other events seem to be for other network locations etc and these seem to occur lots of times through the day.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the most recent logoff event from the computers' eventlogs:

```
Get-EventLog -Computer $strComputer "Security" `
  | ? { $_.EventId -eq 4634 } `
  | sort -Desc TimeGenerated `
  | select -First 1 TimeGenerated
```

Note that reading the Security eventlog requires admin privileges. Also, reading the entire eventlog may require significant amounts of time, so you may want to restrict the processed events by date (`-After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)`) or by number (`-Newest 500`).

Comment: Hi, The problem, with this is that there are loads of 4634 events for today, even though the computer has only been logged in/out once, the other events seem to be for other network locations etc and these seem to occur lots of times through the day.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific about the logoff events you want to select. How do they differ from the other logoff events?

Comment: @Dave - what kind of logoff event are you looking for? Are you looking for: 4647 - User initiated logoff?

Answer (score 0):

This is a better working script over here.
Note that it shows full User Logon/Logoff, but does not show "idle" times.

[User Logon/Logoff Information using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763481/user-logon-logoff-information-using-powershell/31597608#31597608)